# Statsmodels OLS model prediction shape not match?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have trained an OLS model with 10 input variables and 1 response variable. Besides that, I added a constant manually using `add_constant` as provided by Statsmodels.

However, when I try to predict using this model, it raises an error that says

```
ValueError: shapes (1,10) and (11,) not aligned: 10 (dim 1) != 11 (dim 0)
```

My initial thought was that's because I introduced the constant variable, but then since it's a constant after all, am I still required to put it in the prediction input, i.e., something like `predictions = lr.get_prediction(sm.add_constant(out_of_sample_data))`? That seems counter intuitive but I don't know what else can explain this error, besides using `add_constant` turns out to raise the same error again.....

I did some reseach on stackoverflow and most of the question uses `predict()` instead of `get_prediction` like I did, so those are not that helpful. Is one of them better than the other after all?

Check out my full code below:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
lr = sm.OLS(y_train, sm.add_constant(x_train)).fit()
predictions = lr.get_prediction(out_of_sample) #the line where the error was raised
frame = predictions.summary_frame(alpha=0.05
```

Comment: you also need to add the constant to the `out-of-sample` data.